# Strophe.js : How to use strophe.roster.js plugin

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I've found the plugin for maintaining roster in strophe.js.

I found The plugin [here](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/roster/strophe.roster.js), but there's not enough documentation provided.

This is the snippet of the code initialization function:

```
    init: function(conn)
        {
            ...

            var newCallback = function(status)
            {
                if (status == Strophe.Status.ATTACHED || status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Presence subscription
                        conn.addHandler(roster._onReceivePresence.bind(roster), null, 'presence', null, null, null);
                        conn.addHandler(roster._onReceiveIQ.bind(roster), Strophe.NS.ROSTER, 'iq', "set", null, null);
                        console.log(items);
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        Strophe.error(e);
                    }
                }
            };
            ...
            Strophe.addNamespace('ROSTER_VER', 'urn:xmpp:features:rosterver');
        },
```

My problem is I didn't get my roster, so the presence couldn't be updated.

The roster request supposed to be send on init function, but I couldn't find it.

Is anybody use this plugin?

How to get the roster by this plugin since the code is much different from the XMPP Professional Programming book.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it this way. But I agree, all the pluggins are a struggle because there is very little documentation.

See if this helps anyone as this is very old:

```
    /**
 * Called when connection is fully established
 */
function onConnected() {
    // SEE http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#roster-login
    // the order of setting initial presence and requesting the roster is important.
    // Get the roster for the first time (we might need to keep a copy on session storage)
    connection.roster.get(onGetRoster, 0);
    // pres is an strophe helper to represent a presence status. after connecting, we tell the server we are online.
    connection.send($pres());

}

/**
 * When user just connected and gets the roster information
 */
function onGetRoster(items) {
    if (!items || items.length == 0)
        return;
    console.log(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conn.roster.get(rostercb);. Don't forget to set your presence.

Comment: I've try using `roster.get(callback)` but the I didn't get my roster presence :(

Comment: Your presence or people on your roster? The other roster people and you have to have a subscription="both" in order to get presence announcements.

Comment: Presence of people on my roster. The `roster.get()` is a function to get roster from server & push it into `items` array right? I've found that `roster.get()` not set in `init` function, so we must call it manually. The problem is presence handler: `roster._onReceivePresence` **was called before** `roster.get()` in `init` function, so the `items` presence won't collected, because `items` is empty/null.

Comment: I already have a presence handler (connection.addHandler(onPresence, null, 'presence');) that handles any roster presences. The items in the init is what send it to YOUR presence handler when a roster presence happens. If you want to evaluate the roster.get, then include a function with the get (roster.get(onRosterGet);)